# R:subsetting a list using NULL

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a dataset "Boston" in MASS library in R. I want to exclude variables "chas","dis","rad","black","lstat". However the code

```
data[c("chas","dis","rad","black","lstat")]<-NULL
```

doesn't work. Can any on tell me why?

Comment: There's a missing comma : `data[,c("chas","dis","rad","black","lstat")]<-NULL`

Comment: Nope. Same error is reported: `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , c("chas", "dis", "rad", "black",  : 
  replacement has 0 items, need 2530`

Answer (score 2):

```
data[,c("chas","dis","rad","black","lstat")]<- list(NULL)
```

will work. I'm not entirely sure why. My guess is it has to do with how `[<-.data.frame` works - note that `data[,"chas",drop=F] <- NULL` will not work, but `data[,"chas"] <- NULL` will.

Comment: `list(NULL)` is different than NULL and it matches in structure , if not length, the items being erased. And RingTFingM we see "To set entries to NULL, you need x[i] <- list(NULL)."

Answer (score 1):

you can just use

```
Boston[,-which(names(Boston)%in%c("chas","dis","rad","black","lstat"))]
```

Comment: Yes, but OP method works perfectly if you add the appropriate comma.

Comment: @juba I don't believe it will

Comment: @SeñorO Yes, you're right, I only tried to remove one column, but with several ones you have to use `list(NULL)`.

Comment: `-which` is evil. `setdiff` is much safer for these types of operations.